# How to extract tweets between two dates using tweepy from the users of my list? How to do this without giving search keyword?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I need to extract all tweets between two dates using tweepy from the users of my list from 2016 until 2021; so how can i do this without giving search keyword?

```
#Import Libraries
import tweepy
import pandas
import csv
import datetime
import time

#Authentication
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

------------------------------------

username = 'USER_1'
date_since = "2017-01-01"
date_until= "2021-01-01"

tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, screen_name= 'USER_1', since= date_since, until= date_until)
tweets_list = [[tweet.text, tweet.created_at, tweet.user.screen_name] for tweet in tweets]
tweets_df = pandas.DataFrame(tweets_list,columns=['Tweet Text', 'Tweet Datetime', 'username'])
```

[Output]

```
Unexpected parameter: since
Unexpected parameter: until
Unexpected parameter: since
Unexpected parameter: until
...
```

Comment: The [`user_timeline`](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/api.html#tweepy.API.user_timeline) method does not support `since` and `until` date parameters (and user timelines are limited to the most recent 3200 Tweets posted). In order to do what you are looking for, in a date range as far back as 2017, you would need to use the Twitter API v2 full archive search feature. This requires Academic Research level of access.

Comment: This method need a query = '***' for example; But i need extract all tweets (without query ) for a special user ( for example User "X") from 2017 until 2021.
I have Academic Research level of access. @andy-piper